# Why is Pascal's Triangle called a Triangle?

Tags: terminology, binomial-coefficients

Pascal's triangle extends infinitely downwards, meaning in only has two sides. Why then is it called a triangle if a triangle, by definition must have three sides?

Comment: Most illustrations of it don't show the entire thing, in which case it *looks* like a triangle. That's my guess.

Comment: You're right, one should call it the Pascal Cone.

Comment: Pascal's Cone? Can we get a [Koch {snow}flake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) with that?

Comment: It's actually a triangle, [Pascal just didn't have the time to make it shorter](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal#Quotes).

Comment: Why don't you consider the bottom side a side?

Comment: Because the triangle is a good configuration to deduce the "next" coefficients corresponding to the exponent $n+1$ from those of $n$.

Comment: Why is [Pascal's Wager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_Wager#Analysis_with_decision_theory)  still called "Pascal's" when instantiated by someone else who fills the squares and labels with their own content, not necessarily even remotely related to the belief in God?

Comment: It has three sides, each with infinite length.

Comment: So if it has three sides, all of infinite length... then it has infinite area and thus encompasses everything!

Comment: @DoktorJ Everything you *can count*, of course...

Comment: You can "prove" it's a triangle through inference.

Comment: This was meant to be a joke...

Comment: @DoktorJ Not all infinite ranges encompass each other.  As a parallel to your conclusion, the range (0, +∞) is has an infinite length but does not encompass -1 (or any negative number).

Answer (score 39):

[image]

"*Excuse me! Who says my thing does not look a triangle?*"

~ Blaise Pascal

Comment: It looks more like a square to me: :) $$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
&&&&1\\
&&&1&&1\\
&&1&&2&&1\\
&1&&3&&3&&1\\
&&4&&6&&4\\
&&&10&&10\\
&&&&20
\end{array}
$$

Comment: .. and it can be extended in any direction, so it is a plane.

Comment: Did Pascal really say the quoted line ?

Comment: No. Definitely not.

Comment: @A---B no, it was Oscar Wilde.

Answer (score 37):

I find [Pascal's original form](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/TrianguloPascal.jpg) greatly preferable. Slightly modernized:

$$
\begin{array}{ll|llllllllll}
\label{my-label}
  &   & j & → &    &    &     &     &    &    &   &   \\
  &   & 0 & 1 & 2  & 3  & 4   & 5   & 6  & 7  & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
i & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1  & 1   & 1   & 1  & 1  & 1 & 1 \\
↓ & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3  & 4  & 5   & 6   & 7  & 8  & 9 &   \\
  & 2 & 1 & 3 & 6  & 10 & 15  & 21  & 28 & 36 &   &   \\
  & 3 & 1 & 4 & 10 & 20 & 35  & 56  & 84 &    &   &   \\
  & 4 & 1 & 5 & 15 & 35 & 70  & 126 &    &    &   &   \\
  & 5 & 1 & 6 & 21 & 56 & 126 &     &    &    &   &   \\
  & 6 & 1 & 7 & 28 & 84 &     &     &    &    &   &   \\
  & 7 & 1 & 8 & 36 &    &     &     &    &    &   &   \\
  & 8 & 1 & 9 &    &    &     &     &    &    &   &   \\
  & 9 & 1 &   &    &    &     &     &    &    &   &  
\end{array}
$$

This way, it's defined for all $(i, j) \in \mathbb{N}^2$. The identities are nicer, too:

$$T_{i,j} = T_{j, i}$$
$$T_{i,j} = \frac{(i+j)!}{i!j!}$$
$$T_{i+1,j+1} = T_{i+1,j} + T_{i,j+1}$$

Row sum:

$$\sum_{i+j=n}T_{i,j} = 2^n$$

The "hockey stick":

$$T_{i,j+1} = \sum_{0 \leq k \leq i}{T_{k,j}}$$

And finally, for fans of the binomial coefficient:

$$T_{i,j} = \binom{i+j}{i} = \binom{i+j}{j}$$

Of course, the higher-dimensional forms are easy too:

$$T_{\hat{x}} = \frac{(\sum_{x \in \hat{x}}{x})!}{\prod_{x \in \hat{x}}{(x!)}}$$
$$T_{\hat{x}} = T_{\sigma(\hat{x})}$$
$$T_{\hat{x}} = T_{x_1 - 1, x_2, ..., x_n} + T_{x_1, x_2 - 1, ..., x_n} + ... + T_{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n-1}$$

Answer (score 14):

As users basket and Michael Hoppe point out, truncations of Pascal's triangle to finite depth look like triangles, but the whole thing should really be called a cone. Naming conventions are horrible in math to begin with - this is the least of it!! Consider that orthogonal matrices have *orthonormal* columns, or that practically half of theorems with names attached are attributed incorrectly!

Comment: Orthogonal matrices are so named not because their columns are orthogonal but because they preserve a quadratic form, that is, they belong to the orthogonal group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sure, it's just bloody confusing the first time you learn about it

Comment: Everything is confusing until you learn it.

Comment: Nobody is using the "mathematical" characteristics of a triangle or a cone in this case. So it doesn't matter. If you want to be serious, is that angle on the top acute, right or obtuse? And is it really on the top in the first place?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Then why is the group called orthogonal?

Comment: Federico makes a good point. The name "orthogonal group" is misleading, since it *suggests* these are precisely the matrices preserving orthogonality, but that is not a characterization of them. A matrix A in $M_n(\mathbf R)$ preserves orthogonality iff there is a $c \in \mathbf R$ such that $A\mathbf v \cdot A\mathbf w = c(\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf w)$ for all $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ in $\mathbf R^n$. Orthogonal matrices are only the special case $c=1$. Serge Lang points out the misleading nature of the term "orthogonal group" in his graduate algebra book.

Comment: And I would not be surprised if the explanation Mariano suggests is backwards: perhaps the term "orthogonal matrix" came first, so the name "orthogonal group" came from the fact that it consists of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Misattribution *might* be confusing, but calling all results one of Gauss's Lemma, Gauss's Theorem, Euler's Lemma, or Euler's Theorem would be no less confusing.  (Yes, yes.  There may be a little exaggeration there.)  I recall as arguing as a graduate student with another student about the applicability of Gauss's lemma to a problem.  Only took about 30 minutes to figure out that we were each thinking of distinct Gauss's lemmas.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez and then it becomes _horribly_ confusing.

Comment: Why would something that's two-dimensional ever be called a cone?

Comment: And this is an obvious case of misattribution, as the same thing had been studied earlier than Pascal by Chinese mathematicians, by Khayyam and by Tartaglia.

Comment: @MichaelKay It's because of [convex cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone).